# Building thread-safe HDF5 1.8.7 on Windows 7

Tags: multithreading, hdf5

I'm having some rather extreme difficulty getting HDF5 1.8.7 to build from source in Visual Studio 10.  I need to add the thread-safety feature to the library, which according to the FAQ was added in v1.8.6, but not on by default.

I've manually added a "#define H5_HAVE_THREADSAFE 1" line in the h5pubconf.h file in both the /windows/src and /src folders (as I couldn't figure out where I needed to change it in the VS solution itself)

Does anybody have any have any recommendations?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for lack of detail!  O,

Comment: Sorry for lack of detail.  I'm receiving all kinds of unresolved external symbols (eg. H5TS_mutex_unlock, etc.)  My concern is this: if the H5TS* objects aren't even present in the project(s), I really doubt they've been tested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDF5 is using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) to generate a correct build system on various platforms.
It has a [Visual Studio 10 generator](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#gen%3aVisualStudio10).

**You don't have to edit any source file yourself**.
You should [install CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html), choose the Visual Studio 10 generator, and turn on the *threadsafe* build option. It will generate a Visual Studio 10 project ready to be built.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've installed CMake and have been able to create a Visual Studio 2010 project that will build (with a caveat.)  I have been unable to figure out what combination to get it to recognize my external SZIP and ZLIB libraries even after adding the options to point to the include/libs.

Comment: Well, that's a new question… This should be done by editing the `CMakeCache.txt` (or using the GUI) to add/change the paths to SZIP and ZLIB and regenerating the project.

Comment: Was able to get it to work.  Had to add the 4 options: SZIP_INCLUDE_DIR, SZIP_LIBRARY, etc. before configuring the first time. Thanks!